# Inner product and linear isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, isometry

Let $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a real vector space of real polynomials of degree $\le 2$

1) Show that 
$$ \langle p,q\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} p(t)g(t)\,dt,$$

Defines an inner product on $P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Now let $ V = (1,X,X^2)$ be a basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and let 
$$ L_V:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3} \\ \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\ 
    b \\
    c
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a+bX+cX^2$$
be the corresponding linear isomorphism.

2) Find an inner product on $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $L_V$ is a linear isometry.

---

I believe I have done 1 correctly: 
Have to show that the properties of the inner product are true, so: 
a) $\langle p,p\rangle \ge 0$, so: $\int_{-1}^1 p(t)p(t) \, dt=\int_{-1}^1 p(t)^2 \, dt \ge 0$

b) $\langle p,p\rangle = 0 \iff p=0$, so: $\int_{-1}^1 p(t)^2=0 \, dt$

c) $\langle p,q\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 p(t)g(t) \, dt = \int_{-1}^1 q(t)p(t) \, dt = \langle q,p\rangle$

d) $\langle\alpha p + \beta q, r\rangle = \int_{-1}^1(\alpha p+\beta q(t) r(t) \, dt = \alpha \int_{-1}^1 p(t)+\int_{-1}^1 dt \beta q(t) r(t) \, dt = \alpha \langle p,r\rangle + \beta\langle q,r\rangle$

2) I know that a linear transformation is a linear isometry if 
$$\langle L(v_1),L(v_2)\rangle = \langle v_1,v_2\rangle$$
We have that: $L(v_1) = a+bx+cx^2$ and $L(v_2) = d+ex+fx^2$, what am I suppose do to now?

Comment: Try just taking the inner product of $L(v_1)$ and $L(v_2)$ and see what happens

Comment: Standard notation is $\langle p,q\rangle,$ not $<p,q>.$ If you google "latex symbols" you can find things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate 
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle L({\bf v_1}) | L({\bf v_2}) \rangle = \big\langle \sum_{k=0}^2 v_{1,k} x^k \big| \sum_{l=0}^2 v_{2,l} x^k\big\rangle = \sum_{k,l} v_{1,l} v_{k,l}  \color{blue}{\langle x^k|x^l\rangle} = \sum_{k,l} v_{1,k}  \color{blue}{\alpha_{k,l} }v_{1,l} = {\bf v_1}^T A {\bf v_2}
\end{eqnarray}

Where I have defined the matrix $A$ with entries

$$
\alpha_{k,l} = \langle x^k | x^l \rangle
$$

So $L$ is a linear isometry if ${\bf v_1}^T A {\bf v_2}$ is an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$, can you take it from here? (Note that $A = A^T$)